# Installing QuantLib on ios 10.9

Tags: osx-mavericks, quantlib

I try to get QuantLib working on my macbook.
But I don't know how to interpret the note in the instructions:

> A note on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)
>
> Users have reported linking problems under Mac OS X 10.9; the solution
>   (thanks to Albert Azout for pointing it out) seems to be to set the
>   environment flags CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS to -stlib=libstdc++
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 before compiling.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you're following the instructions [here](http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml), you'll be compiling from the command line. In this case, you can set the variables in a few ways; I think the most convenient is to pass them to `configure` as in:

```
./configure --enable-static --with-boost-include=/opt/local/include/ \
            --with-boost-lib=/opt/local/lib/ --prefix=/opt/local/ \
            CXXFLAGS="-stlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6" \
            LDFLAGS="-stlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6"
```

after which they'll be used by `make` to build the library.

(If you're using an IDE, I'm afraid you're on your own; you'll have to refer to its manual

Comment: not really working. error message is as follows: configure: error: in `/Users/user/Desktop/QuantLib-1.6.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: That points to a compiler misconfiguration: QuantLib is not even used during `./configure`. Did you install the command-line tools correctly? Can you compile and run a simple "hello world" program from the command line?